# How to use a Custom iOS View(located in a referenced Class Library) in an Interface Builder file?

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, custom-view

I have two projects. The first one is the iOS-App which is referencing a class library with the target framework `Xamarin.iOS`. In that class library I implemented a `CustomView` which inherits from `UIView`. I also registered it with the `"Register"` attribute.

So in the interface designer I get the prefilled information to use this class as custom class after I dragged the `UIView` to my `ViewController`. But when I run the app I get the following information:

```
"Unknown class MyCustomView in Interface Builder file."
```

If I move the my `CustomView` from the class library project into my first project then it will run as expected.

Does someone know how to use a `CustomView`, which is located in a referenced class library, in an Interface Builder file?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to `Register` accross project boundaries. In my tests, even when you use the exact same namespace, you still end up with an error.

What *is* possible, on the other hand, is to use a proxy class and make use of inheritance to bring the desired behaviour to the proxy.

Basically, it boils down to this:

1) In your library, you define your Custom `UIView` and implement any behaviour you want to share:

```
public class MyCustomUIView : UIView
{
    public MyCustomUIView(IntPtr ptr) : base (ptr)
    {
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        // Do something beautiful here...
        AddSubview(new UILabel(new CGRect(0,0,200,30)) { Text = "I live in the library"});
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    }
}
```

Note that we don't `Register`this class, because it won't work anyway.

2) Now in your app project, open up the storyboard in interface designer or XCode and **assign a completely new name** to your placeholder `UIView`. In my case, I chose `MyCustomUIViewProxy`. Xamarin studio will create two files for you: MyCustomUIViewProxy.cs and MyCustomUIViewProxy2.designer.cs. Note that in the designer.cs file, Xamarin automatically `Register`ed your proxy class.

3) Now all we have to do is use inheritance, to make the proxy act like the original: In MyCustomUIViewProxy.cs, we change the base class from `UIView` to `MyCustomUIView`, and we're good to go:

```
partial class MyCustomUIViewProxy : MyCustomUIView
{
    public MyCustomUIViewProxy (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
}
```

That's it:

[image]